# Connecting to WebSocket with Starscream in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, starscream

Just a quick question. I am to connect to a Server through a web socket,  but I confess I have no previous experience with that technology, and little experience with networking in general.

So, I am using StarScream, and, in AppDelegate I add this as a property:

```
var socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "http://<IP>:<port>/")!)
```

Then in didFinnishLaunching I do:

```
socket.delegate = self
socket.connect()
```

The client tries to connect, bu I get a timeout error.

Specifically,

```
//The socket timed out waiting to be ready to write.
```

I can connect to the web socket from the browser, so I know it's working, but I have no idea what the problem might be. I looked, I didn't find this problem anywhere, so I wonder if there is something I am misunderstanding.

There is the protocol argument in the WebSocket call, but I'm not sure what to put there.

Any tips would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm also getting this error when trying to reconnect to the socket.

Comment: @TomSpee Yes... sort of.. My problem was that I was trying to connect to a socketIO server in a Flask app. socketIO is a higher level protocol, so it's not compatible with a websocket protocol. I switched to SocketIO and it worked perfectly. But I don't know what you have on the backend. If you give me more info about your problem I may have some tips... Also, https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/issues/542